# Make utility deletes PDF when Ctrl-C'ing out of continuous preview

Tags: latexmk, workflow, makefile

I am using a Makefile together with the `latexmk` utility to build PDFs from LaTeX files. My question is at the bottom. Here is some background:

The relevant parts of my Makefile are the following:

```
LATEX=pdflatex
LATEXOPT=--shell-escape --file-line-error
NONSTOP=--interaction=nonstopmode
LATEXMK=latexmk
LATEXMKOPT=-quiet -pdf
CONTINUOUS=-pvc

%.pdf: %.tex
    @${LATEXMK} ${LATEXMKOPT} ${CONTINUOUS} \
      -pdflatex="${LATEX} ${LATEXOPT} ${NONSTOP} %O %S" $<
```

This structure is adapted from the example in [this link](https://drewsilcock.co.uk/using-make-and-latexmk/).

I compile a LaTeX source `file.tex` into `file.pdf` using

```
make file.pdf
```

This runs `latexmk` on `file.tex` and continuously recompiles it (using the `-pvc` "preview continuously" option) with `pdflatex` whenever `file.tex` is modified. Combined with a PDF viewer that updates automatically, this lets me edit `file.tex` and see the updated PDF whenever I save.

This works perfectly while `latexmk` runs in the background. The problem is when I want to end `latexmk`. It tells me

```
=== Watching for updated files. Use ctrl/C to stop ...
```

As soon as I type `Ctrl-C`, `make` says

```
make: *** Deleting file `file.pdf'
```

I believe this is because I stopped building the `file.pdf` target abruptly, so `make` thinks something went wrong. Therefore, my question is

> How do I preview continuously and exit `latexmk`, all while using `make`, without the PDF being deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After asking this question I read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Interrupts.html) from the `make` documentation. It turns out that `make` does not delete the dependencies of the special target `.PRECIOUS` when interrupted. Adding the line

```
.PRECIOUS: %.pdf
```

seems to solve my problem.